# Combine different data sets using rbind()

Tags: r, statistics

I am now doing a project and facing a problem of combining multiple datasets into one dataset. However, when I was trying to combine these items with `rbind` function, I can only combine the first two datasets. When combining more than three, there is a message saying

> Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
>   names do not match previous names

Here is my code:

````
```{r, message=FALSE}
require(mosaic); require(Sleuth2); require(MASS); require(leaps)
options(digits=3)
trellis.par.set(theme=col.mosaic())  # get a better color scheme for lattice
BelgiumMa <-read.csv("BelgiumMa.csv")
BrazilCh<- read.csv("BrazilCh.csv")
BosSerb <- read.csv("BosSerb.csv")
NetherSpain <- read.csv("NetherSpain.csv")
TunisiaSouth <- read.csv("TunisiaSouth.csv")
BangMala <- read.csv("BangMala.csv")
HonBraz <- read.csv("HonBraz.csv")
MalaChin <- read.csv("MalaChin.csv")
DenSwit <- read.csv("DenSwit.csv")
CamNic <- read.csv("CamNic.csv")
total <- rbind(BelgiumMa, BrazilCh, BosSerb, NetherSpain, TunisiaSouth, BangMala,
HonBraz, MalaChin, DenSwit, CamNic)
```
````

Comment: Try `rbind.fill` from plyr package. I think the column names are differnt in each dataset.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(plyr)
rbind.fill(BelgiumMa, BrazilCh, BosSerb, NetherSpain, TunisiaSouth, BangMala,
HonBraz, MalaChin, DenSwit, CamNic)
```